# Can't make Celery always_eager in FastAPI

Tags: python, celery, fastapi

I am trying to implement queues inside a FastAPI application. I have manually checked whether it connects to the broker and sends messages and it's all OK. However, for testing purposes I would like to get rid of the need to launch broker by setting the "[task_always_eager](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#task-always-eager)" option. The project layout is as follows:

```bash
$ tree -I '*pyc|venv' src tests
src
├── celery_app.py
├── celeryconf.py
├── db.py
├── main.py
├── __pycache__
├── red_link
│   ├── connectors.py
│   ├── exceptions.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── services.py
│   ├── tasks.py
│   └── views.py
├── settings.py
└── throttling
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── middleware.py
    └── __pycache__
tests
├── conftest.py
├── fixtures
│   └── casettes
│       ├── test_sends_sms_fails.yml
│       └── test_sends_sms.yml
├── __pycache__
└── test_redlink_sms_sending.py

8 directories, 18 files
```

The `celery_app.py` configuration:

```py
from celery import Celery
from settings import get_settings


settings = get_settings()


def create_celery_app() -> Celery:
    celery = Celery(
        "sms_sender",
        broker=settings.celery_broker_url,
        include=["red_link.tasks"],
    )
    celery.config_from_object("celeryconf")
    return celery


app = create_celery_app()
```

And the `celeryconf.py`:

```py
from settings import get_settings


settings = get_settings()

task_always_eager = settings.celery_task_always_eager
```

The environment variable that sets the "always eager" option is set correctly:

[image: Debugger hangs on the environment variable creation and shows that the always eager option is set to true]

But when I launch pytest it fails as it tries to connect to the broker:

```
=============================================================================================== short test summary info ===============================================================================================
FAILED tests/test_redlink_sms_sending.py::test_sends_sms - kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
FAILED tests/test_redlink_sms_sending.py::test_sends_sms_fails - kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
FAILED tests/test_redlink_sms_sending.py::test_send_sms_fails_with_error_connection - kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: Couple of ideas to try: #1 is dropping a breakpoint into [`celery.canvas.apply_async`](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/bd590c0965969845e3faed616475d17d468bbf47/celery/canvas.py#L1032) to check the value of `app.conf.task_always_eager`. And then #2 would be to see what happens when you initialize Celery with `task_always_eager=True`, your `create_celery_app` function. Not sure what's going on, but I'd do those things real quick just as some basic measures to see if it behaves differently.